# PhpWord-TemplateProcessor does not replace values

Tags: php, templates, phpword, phpoffice

I'm trying to replace some content into a docx file but even if the `saveAs` works properly I dont see any modification in the new document.
Here is my code :

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor;
use Mpdf\Mpdf;

// Chemin du fichier Word d'origine
$inputDocx = 'Attestation_CLUE_modele V1 .docx';

// Chemin du fichier Word modifié
$outputDocx = 'Attestation_CLUE_modele V1MODA.docx';

// Instancier le TemplateProcessor
$templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor($inputDocx);

// Remplacer le texte avec des guillemets français
$templateProcessor->setValues(['NOM', 'TEST DU NOM']);
var_dump($templateProcessor);
// Sauvegarder le document Word modifié
$templateProcessor->saveAs($outputDocx);
```

and here is what I'm trying to replace :
[image]

Yet nothing change, at first I was trying with the full version of what I want to change :

```
$templateProcessor->setValues(['«NOM»', 'TEST DU NOM']);
```

But without success and even without the `«»` that could maybe have caused some encoding issue (maybe), nothing changed

Comment: The setValues method you're using is not a part of the official PHPWord library. Instead, you should use the setValue method to replace placeholders in your template. Placeholders in your Word template should be in the format ${placeholder}.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setValue` method to replace each placeholder individually

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor;

// Chemin du fichier Word d'origine
$inputDocx = 'Attestation_CLUE_modele V1 .docx';

// Chemin du fichier Word modifié
$outputDocx = 'Attestation_CLUE_modele V1MODA.docx';

// Instancier le TemplateProcessor
$templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor($inputDocx);

// Remplacer le texte
$templateProcessor->setValue('NOM', 'TEST DU NOM');

// Sauvegarder le document Word modifié
$templateProcessor->saveAs($outputDocx);
```